# Vitali covering problem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $ R $ denote the set of rational numbers in $ [0,1] $ and for each $ r∈R $, let $ V_r  = \{ [r,r+ 1/k] : k=1,2,3,\ldots\} $. Put $V = ⋃_r  V_r $.

Show that for every  $ ε > 0 $ there exists a countable collection $\{ I_n \}$ of pairwise disjoint intervals in **V** such that $ R ⊂ ⋃_n  I_n $ and $ m \left( ⋃_n I_n \right) < ε$.

I proved that  **V** is a vitali covering of $ R $. Now how I can prove the rest?!

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the need to use Vitali covering lemma here. List all rationals $r_1, r_2, \dots $. Inductively choose intervals $I_1, I_2, \dots$ in $V$ such that $I_n$ is disjoint from previously chosen intervals, $|I_n| < \epsilon/2^n$ and $r_n \in \bigcup_{j \leq n} I_j$.